# When writing a program in c++ using multiple files does every class need its own?

Tags: c++, file

Using multiple files in a program especially larger programs saves much hassle and even more scrolling for the user, but is it necessary to have separate .cpp and .h files for every class or object I wish to represent in my application? Is it better to group classes into modules of several logically related classes where they share the .cpp and .h files?

Thanks.

Comment: Use one .h & .cpp per class. If you want to group multiple classes into a "module" use namespaces.

Comment: I agree with Borgleader, the only negative about this though is if you end up with a very large number of classes and there for implementation files, you compilation / linking times will increase a lot over combining then in fewer files.

Comment: You can have multiple classes in a file if you wish. What @Borgleader is describing is good practice, but not a language requirement.

Comment: I know that it will work i was just wondering if there was some degree of uniformity in opinion or a perhaps a reason why one might be better than the other.  What exactly is a namespace i know namespace std but would you mind giving me your best simple description?

Comment: You have to do what makes sense for you.  Often you'll have several very closely related classes, perhaps a set of small ones whose sole purpose is to be members of a larger one.  You might group all of these closely related classes into a single source (.cpp) file.  Also, if the code you're working on is used by something else (e.g. perhaps you're working on a library module), you probably want to put the entire API in a single header (.h) file, even if the class implementations themselves are spread among multiple source files.  That would make it easier for your users to include one header.

Comment: One file per *object* would be rather extreme!

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not necessary to have separate .cpp and .h files for every class, although it is a common practice as an organizational technique. It is particularly helpful if you (or the person trying to use your code) are not using a feature rich IDE e.g. a text editor. If you can't identify the contents of a file from it's name, then you are going to have a hard time locating classes in a large project. Even with an IDE such as Visual Studio, I like the convenience of having one class per file, because I can then navigate through my classes without having to use the class explorer or some other tool.

You gave the example of mixing multiple classes into one source and one header file, but another alternative you didn't mention is that you can place everything in the header file, which can be useful, for example to create header only libraries (which means the user only has to worry about including your headers), or for templates.